# difference-in-difference analysis in R results in 0 degrees of freedom

Tags: r, regression

I have a value I am measuring before and after a treatment, for an experimental group and a control group (total of 4 data points).

An example CSV file of the data is [here](http://pastebin.com/d0ZuWgiS).

When I model it as follows:

```
general_df <- read.csv('general.csv')
general_model <- lm(value ~ group + pre_post + group*pre_post, data=general_df)
summary(general_model)
```

I get this output:

```
Residuals:
ALL 4 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)     100         NA      NA       NA
group           20         NA      NA       NA
pre_post        -50         NA      NA       NA
group:pre_post    -10         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 3 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

How do I do this analysis correctly so I don't have 0 degrees of freedom and NA values everywhere?

Is the problem that I'm using averages, instead of the raw values?  Ie. the values reported are averages of tens of thousands of values.

Answer (score 2):

Your data only include one measurement per level of your model specification (control/pre, control/post, experimental/pre, experimental/post), so the model perfectly interpolates the data and there's no measurement of random variability.

Your intuition is correct - using the raw data will allow the model to compare the size of the effects with the variability of the data and provide effect tests to help you understand which differences are probably just random variability, and which differences are likely associated with the treatment.